# jQuery auto increment number on td table

Tags: jquery

How to add increment number on `table` if new row added using jQuery?

```
<table>
  <th>No.</th>
  <th>Name</th>

  <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <tr>
  <td>2</td>
</table>
```

Here is the code for add new row

```
var num = 1;
$('table').prepend('<tr><td align="center" class="number">'+(num+1)+'</td><td>'+jsonStr.departmentName+'</td></tr>');
```

So the new row added will show on top.
Before:

```
No | Name
1  | David
2  | Mark
```

After new row added:

```
No   | Name
auto | based on added
2    | David
3    | Mark
```

Comment: what is happening with what you have now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work out your html a little bit to ease your task:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <th>No.</th>
      <th>Name</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="center number">1</td>
         <td>David</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="center number">2</td>
         <td>Mark</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

After that manipulating the number becomes easy:

```
var jsonStr = {
    departmentName : "Sales"
};
var newrow = $('<tr><td class="center number"></td><td>'+jsonStr.departmentName+'</td></tr>');
$("tbody").prepend(newrow);

$("td.number").each(function(i,v) {
    $(v).text(i + 1);
});
```

Demo
https://jsfiddle.net/w7csmhwk/

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do that then first create one input field with type hidden like this and store you row number on that hidden input's as a value

```
<input type="hidden" name="rowNum" value="">
```

And finally whenever you add row throught jQuery change its value by jQuery like this

```
 $('rowNum').val("your latest row")
```

and get set the value of your row

Answer (score 0):

First you would need to know about the previously existing rows, then insert, then correct all of the row numbers for the existing rows:

```
// Find existing rows first
var $trs = $('table').children("tr");

// Then do your prepend/insert, I'm assuming your first row always get the value of 1
$('table').prepend('<tr><td align="center" class="number">1</td><td>'+jsonStr.departmentName+'</td></tr>');

// Then update all the existing values
$trs.each(function (index) {
    var $tdNumber = $(this).first("td.number");
    $tdNumber.text(index + 2 /* Offset by the number of rows inserted plus 1 to make it ordinal */);
});
```

Comment: Hi, just tried the code. the next row is not updating the number.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btnAdd").click(function(){
    
    $("table tr").each(function(){
      var tr=$(this);
      var ftd=tr.find("td:first");
      var std=tr.find("td:last");
      var tmpvalue=parseInt(ftd.text());
      tr.html("<tr><td>"+(tmpvalue+1)+"</td><td>"+std.text()+"</td></tr>");
    });
    $("table").prepend("<tr><td>1</td><td>Michael</td></tr>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>David</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Roy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" class="btnAdd" value="Add" />
```

**The main logic should be,**

1 - The new record inserted will always be number 1, so you can statically put 1 for first td

2 - Iterate through each `tr` and then settle the `Id` by incrementing it by one

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonStr = {
    departmentName : "Sales"
};
```

What does this code snippet mean in this code :

```
var jsonStr = {
    departmentName : "Sales"
};

var newrow = $('<tr><td class="center number"></td><td>' + jsonStr.departmentName + '</td></tr>');
$("tbody").prepend(newrow);

$("td.number").each(function(i,v) {
    $(v).text(i + 1);
});
```